# It is possible to run an Elasticsearch 5.x with Flink 1.2.0?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-flink, elasticsearch-2.0, apache-kafka-connect

It is possible to run elasticsearch version 5.x in Apache Flink 1.2.0?
I cannot upgrade my Flink to 1.3 because I need the 1.2.0 version to run kafka.

by what it is said in this link : https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/connectors/elasticsearch.html

flink-connector-elasticsearch5_2.10 (Supported since) 1.2.0 (Elasticsearch version) 5.x

This connector should work (since that my Flink version it is 1.2.0), but when I run it it doesn't work.

Do I need to install Elasticsearch 2.x or there is some other way to make it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation was incorrect, and has been updated to reflect the fact that support for Elasticsearch 5.x was added to Flink after 1.2 -- i.e., it is currently in Flink 1.3-SNAPSHOT.